# Cocoa Message Pump?

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, objective-c++

I am trying to implement a Cocoa message pump.  I do not have much experience with Cocoa API, but I managed to implement a rudimentary pump using `NSApp nextEventMatchingMask`.

The problem with this approach is that I do not get all of the events, and the ones I do seem to be only for the main window, not any of the widgets on the window.

My UI's are generated in code (no nibs) and I am not using the Cocoa runLoop (thus the need for a message pump).  I am trying to keep all Objective-C++ and Cocoa code to a minimum in this.

The need is to loop over all in-coming events and dispatch them to appropriate functions to handle them depending on the object and the event.

Here is pseudo-code to show what I mean (and what I have, mostly, except it only does "main window" events)

```
event = GetNextEvent();
while (event)
{
    if(event->type == MOUSE_DOWN) 
    { mouse_down(event->target); }
    event = GetNextEvent();
}
```

Is there some trick to this on OS X?

Comment: Using NSApp with no runloop in place is unlikely to be successful. Using AppKit windows and controls is pretty much guaranteed to not be.

Comment: Is this just speculation or do you have something concrete? Using NSApp with no runLoop is currently successful for all of the messages of the parent window, so it is already most of the way there.  If I can also get the messages of the children (which seems like a reasonable request) then it would be a complete success.

Comment: All parts of AppKit that use NSTimer, -performSelectorAfterDelay:, CFRunLoopPerformBlock, etc... require a runloop to function. I'm not speculating, but you'd probably need to break out Hopper and disassemble a bit to see evidence of it.

Comment: (For example NSAnimation is timer-based)

Comment: @Catfish_Man I have no need for anything other than "generic" widgets (i.e. buttons, labels, lists, etc...).  I cannot allow "control" to pass to any blocking function like a runLoop.  If I could "ping" (run once) a runLoop (which would be very similar to a "do events") that would suffice as well.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but as mentioned in the comments already -

it's not a good idea trying to mimick a **Classic Mac OS 7** style run loop with Cocoa as pretty much everything (timers, notifications, events, queues, ...) in AppKit relies on the existence of a 'proper' `NSRunLoop` in **every thread** of a Cocoa app.

You can check [this page on CocoaDev](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/RunLoop) or the [NSRunLoop docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSRunLoop_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more in-depth information.

For a minimalistic Cocoa sample app check out this great blog post on the '*Cocoa With Love*' blog:
**[Minimalist Cocoa programming](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/minimalist-cocoa-programming.html)**

Comment: I am not interested in using a Cocoa runLoop.  There is no (explicit) run loop in my application so a "do events" message pump is the only (optimal) solution.  I do not care for timers, notifications, or anything other than the interaction events "click, mouse move, etc..." of the window and widgets.  I am not "building a Cocoa app" so much as I am allowing windows and widgets to be (optionally) created/manipulated in an existing application in a platform agnostic (as much as possible) manner.